# Change User Registration

Tags: user-registration

I want to change the fields/functionality of the WordPress registration.
In the following ways:

1. User specify their e-mail and desired password (no username).
2. I want the user to have to confirm their e-mail before their account is activated.
3. I want a few more fields (I am going to offer a paid and a free membership).

Is there a good way that I can utilize the existing WordPress register form?  Or should I create one from scratch?

Answer (score 1):

You can't really eliminate usernames, they are an essential part of Wordpress core. The best you could do was create a custom form and then save the data to the DB using the built-in fields.

For example, you could set the email they enter to equal both the email and the username field so both are the same.

I would suggest creating your own form and then saving the the database yourself instead of trying to fork the existing login form, which would most likely be a headache considering what you're trying to do.

Or, unless you're completely opposed to plugins, a combinations of Advanced Custom Fields and Theme My Login could probably take care of everything for you.

Comment: If I make it so that a user can change their username - will that have any big negative ramifications?

Comment: WordPress is designed for users with static usernames, so yes.